# 'Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension' not found after sf 3.1 > 3.4 update

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

I upgraded my project from Symfony 3.1 to Symfony 3.4

Using this tutorial:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_minor.html

Project seemed to be working on app_dev.php, but when I ran it on the app.php it displaying following error:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension' not found in /Users/yyy/Sites/xxx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/FormExtension.php on line 32
```

Do you have any idea how can I fix it?

I already tried with

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

And with:

```
composer update twig/twig
```

None of these works.

Comment: try `composer update` and / or `cache:clear`?

Comment: what are the differences between environments? possibly config stuff for local env but not prod?

Comment: also, try deleting vendor.lock, vendor dir, and doing install again. and clear cache for all environments

Comment: Do you have already see [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.2.md#twigbridge)?

Comment: Didn't notice that yet, It can be the key to this problem. But I don't clearly understand how to implement those changes, should I edit the vendor packages(it's what I understand from this article, but it's no sense for me) or how to fix it to work with symfony 3.4? I mean the TwigBridge block.